# Windows DLL linker errors with template class

Tags: c++, windows, dll

```
template <typename SenderType__, typename... Args__>
class CORE_API Event
{
public:
  typedef typename std::function<void(const SenderType__*, Args__ ...)> EventHandler;  

  Event& operator+=(const EventHandler& toSubscribe)
  {
    Subscribe(toSubscribe);
    return *this;
  }

  void operator()(const SenderType__* sender, Args__ ... args) const
  {
    Invoke(sender, args...);
  }

  void Subscribe(const EventHandler& toSubscribe)
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(m_callbackMutex);
    m_callbacks.push_back(toSubscribe);
  }

  void Clear()
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(m_callbackMutex);
    m_callbacks.clear();
  }

  void Invoke(const SenderType__* sender, Args__ ... args) const
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(m_callbackMutex);
    for (auto iter = m_callbacks.begin(); iter != m_callbacks.end(); ++iter)
    {
      (*iter)(sender, args...);
    }
  }

private:
  std::vector<EventHandler> m_callbacks;
  mutable std::mutex m_callbackMutex;
};

template class CORE_API Event<std::string, std::string>;
```

In a consumer of the DLL....

```
TEST(EventTest, TestEventFiresAndPassesArgs)
{
  Event<std::string, std::string> event;
  event += &TestFunction;
  event += &TestFunction2;
  std::string sender = "TestEventFiresAndPassesArgs";
  std::string arg = "boo!";
  event.Invoke(&sender, arg);
  ASSERT_EQ(sender, testEventFiresAndPassesArgsSenderName);
  ASSERT_EQ(arg, testEventFiresAndPassesArgsTestArg);
  ASSERT_EQ(sender + "Function2", testEventFiresAndPassesArgsSenderName2);
  ASSERT_EQ(arg + "Function2", testEventFiresAndPassesArgsTestArg2);
}
```

Then the linker output is:

```
EventTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class CompanyName::Utils::Event<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > & __cdecl CompanyName::Utils::Event<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >::operator+=(class std::function<void __cdecl(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)> const &)" (__imp_??Y?$Event@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@Utils@CompanyName@@QEAAAEAV012@AEBV?$function@$$A6AXPEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@Z@std@@@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual void __cdecl EventTest_TestEventFiresAndPassesArgs_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@EventTest_TestEventFiresAndPassesArgs_Test@@EEAAXXZ)
2>EventTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl CompanyName::Utils::Event<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >::Invoke(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)const " (__imp_?Invoke@?$Event@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@Utils@CompanyName@@QEBAXPEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V45@@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual void __cdecl EventTest_TestEventFiresAndPassesArgs_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@EventTest_TestEventFiresAndPassesArgs_Test@@EEAAXXZ)
2>EventTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl CompanyName::Utils::Event<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >::Event<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >(void)" (__imp_??0?$Event@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@Utils@CompanyName@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __cdecl EventTest_TestEventFiresAndPassesArgs_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@EventTest_TestEventFiresAndPassesArgs_Test@@EEAAXXZ)
2>EventTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl CompanyName::Utils::Event<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >::~Event<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >(void)" (__imp_??1?$Event@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@Utils@CompanyName@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __cdecl EventTest_TestEventFiresAndPassesArgs_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@EventTest_TestEventFiresAndPassesArgs_Test@@EEAAXXZ)
2>..\runCoreUnitTests.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Is that a header file or what

Comment: @Alf it's a header file. This is a lib compiled into a dll. Then the consumer is my unit test executable--it's a cpp file..

Comment: Hmm, then what does CORE_API mean?  You cannot export templates from a DLL.

Comment: #if defined (_MSC_VER)
#pragma warning(disable : 4251)
  #ifdef Core_EXPORTS
    #define  CORE_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #define  CORE_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif /* Core_EXPORTS */
#else /* defined (_WIN32) */
#define CORE_API
#endif

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf If I cannot export templates then they are almost worthless, and MSFT compilers suck bigtime.

Comment: you don't need the `__declspec()` nonsense for templates. If you remove `CORE_API` and just use `template <....> class Event`, I think everything will be OK.

Comment: @RSahu ok, one sec let me try that.

Comment: @RSahu that worked please explain that to me.....

Comment: Templates are used to generate code at compile time. `__declspec()` is used for exporting code for use in another program, which is unnecessary for templates (as the external program merely uses your template to generate its own code)

Comment: Adding to what @RedAlert said, templates don't generate code in the DLL by default - they generate code in the calling program. There are ways to force them to generate code in the DLL, then you *would* need the `__declspec`.

Comment: *MSFT compilers suck bigtime* - This has nothing to do with the compiler, the limitation is the basic nature of how templates work. Have you tried adding `template class CORE_API Event<std::string, std::string>;` in the file with your unit test? Maybe also try adding `extern` in front of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need functions to be exported using `__declspec(dllexport)` when creating a DLL.

You can use such functions from another DLL by declaring those functions using `__declspec(dllimport)`.

These work great for regular functions.

However, for class templates and function templates, the templates are instantiated on an as needed basis. They don't get exported to the DLL in which they are defined. Hence, they can't get imported from the DLL either. For this reason, you don't use `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)` with class templates and function templates.

Comment: That would seem to indicate to me that you can't use templates that a DLL defines.

Comment: When you define a template in a DLL, the classes/functions don't really get defined until someone tries instantiate the templates. templates are just like blueprints. They are there to build concrete classes and functions.

Comment: There is an explicit instantiation (last line of the first code block) that is being exported. This *should* be possible, although I've never tried it myself /cc @JonathanHenson

Comment: Thanks for great and simple explanation about export/import class/function templates from dynamic library!
I had a problem with compiling a dll.
I made an error by exporting all classes and class templates from dll (I tried to compile linux dll and simple added EXPORT macros to all classes by find and replace).
I had a lot of not related to the problem errors.
Then, I found your post here, deleted all EXPORT macroses with class templates and the errors were gone:)